# How to get Alt Shortcuts in Custom Taskpane on Microsoft Office?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, shortcut

I had created a Powerpoint VSTO add-in using C#.Net and created a Taskpane.

Like all, i used a Windows Forms UserControl and then binded it to Custom Taskpane.

Inside taskpane, i have list of buttons and checkboxes (Example &Button1, &Checkbox1 etc), but when i open taskpane and press Alt key, i can't see the underline on the control or unable to use Alt shortcut like in windows forms.

Please help me to achieve this.